# Using java, how do you get the amount of free space on a solaris zfs file system?

Tags: java, file-io, zfs

Using java, how do you get the amount of free space on a solaris zfs file system?

I have a SunFire x4140 with built-in hdd mounted as /. It also has a connected JBOD with 7.6TB of HDD space, configured as a ZFS file system and mounted as /app.

I use java.io.File.getUsableSpace or java.io.File.getFreeSpace to get the amount of free space on the file system. On / (the on-board) HDD FS it works correctly.

On /app (the zfs partition) File.getFreeSpace, File.getUsableSpace  and File.getTotalSpace all return 0 (zero). Does anyone know why? Does java.io.File.getUsableSpace work on ZFS, and if so, how?

The following shows the zfs file system on the machine in question:

> /usr/sbin/zfs list

```
NAME                USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
internal            196K  98.4G     1K  none
internal/logs        18K  98.4G    18K  /logs
j4200-1             442G  7.57T  2.44K  none
j4200-1/app         442G  7.57T   153M  /app
j4200-1/app@first   442G      -   442G  -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why, but you may be take a look at [libzfs](https://zfs.dev.java.net/), that wraps zfs command in a nice java API

Comment: Want to avoid writing file system specific code. But if our current workaround becomes too clumsy this might be considered.

Comment: As you explicitly ask for ZFS I don't quite get why you dismiss this answer. If you want a non file system specific answer you need to rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1):

The df -kP command returns the free space, 
but the most universal way is to use

Apache Commons IO 
 [FileSystemUtils.freeSpaceKb("/volume");](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileSystemUtils.html#freeSpaceKb%28java.lang.String%29)

it utilize df as well as dir for Windows

Answer (score 0):

What does the "df" command report? Is that also not reporting free space on zfs correctly?

Comment: df works 100%. I'm using a workaround/hack, where I call df via processBuilder and parse the output for the available space. Not pretty.